# Unread Emails for Exchange 2016

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2016

I used to get unread emails for multiple users using the EWSUtil library from the link bellow with Exchange server2010.

https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2008/11/find-unused-mailbox-powershell-gui.html

Code:

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\EWSUtil.dll")

$mails=( "user0", "user1", "user2")
ForEach ($mail in $mails)
{
$mbcombCollection = @()

$specificuser = get-mailbox $mail

    $mbcomb = "" | select DisplayName,EmailAddress, Unread
    $mbcomb.DisplayName = $specificuser.DisplayName.ToString()
    $mbcomb.EmailAddress = $specificuser.WindowsEmailAddress.ToString()
    $mbMailboxEmail = $specificuser.WindowsEmailAddress.ToString()

    $ewc = new-object EWSUtil.EWSConnection($mbMailboxEmail,$false, $null,$null,$null,$null)
    $dTypeFld = new-object EWSUtil.EWS.DistinguishedFolderIdType
    $dTypeFld.Id = [EWSUtil.EWS.DistinguishedFolderIdNameType]::inbox

    $mbMailbox = new-object EWSUtil.EWS.EmailAddressType
    $mbMailbox.EmailAddress = $mbMailboxEmail
    $dTypeFld.Mailbox = $mbMailbox

    $fldarry = new-object EWSUtil.EWS.BaseFolderIdType[] 1
    $fldarry[0] = $dTypeFld

    $fldList = $ewc.GetFolder($fldarry)
    [EWSUtil.EWS.FolderType]$pfld = [EWSUtil.EWS.FolderType]$fldList[0];
        $mbcomb.Unread = $pfld.UnreadCount
    $mbcombCollection += $mbcomb
$mbcombCollection
Add-Content C:\UnreadEmailCheck1.txt $mbcombCollection
}
```

But now I can't get the unread emails count with Exchange server 2016 (after I did the migration of my Exchange).

Comment: What exactly IS the question here? you've posted a statement. Could you share what you've done to try and fix whatever the issue is with us? Can you show examples of data? can you add anything which you'd imagine would help with identifying the issue?

Comment: this script is written to give as result : user mailbox + number of unread messages as output, it was working perfect on Exchange server 2010.But After migration to Exchange 2016, the script returns just the name of the mailbox and give a blank to number of unread emails, with no error while running it.

Answer (score 0):

This library is not working with Exchange 2016, the person who wrote this library [Glen Scales](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/glen%20scales/?ws=usercard-mini) suggested the following solution:

Use this script:
https://github.com/gscales/Powershell-Scripts/blob/master/unReadModule2016.ps1

and also grab the latest EWS Managed API (compiled from git hub) 
https://github.com/gscales/Powershell-Scripts/blob/master/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.zip 
put the dll in the same directory as the script.

Then run

Import-Module .\unReadModule2016.ps1

(this will import the module cmdlets)

and use

Get-UnReadCountOnFolder -MailboxName user@mailbox.com